# Angularjs full stack application

Tags: angularjs

Hi guys im using angularjs full stack (yoeman+express+mongodb) application for development, im developing the application in the sample scaffold provided. Structure of project is

```
app
 -scripts
 -styles
 -views
   -- admin
   --partials
   --404.html
   --index.html
lib
```

now my issue is partials folder contains navbar.html and foter.html , which is included in index.html page

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navbar'"></div>
<div style="height:48px;" id="spacer"></div>
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div ng-view=""></div>
<div ng-include="'partials/footer'"></div>
```

all the html page in partials have navbar and footer thats ok , but i want admin folder pages to not contain any of these navbar and footer. after checking all the app.js and route.js im not able to find what is the setting to be done so that all the admin folder pages should not have index.html page structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the a third party router such as angular-ui-router which has multiple views and nested states to show different views or not show them at all depending on URL.

Please see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: can we do it without using any third party router, i just want to know how/why all the pages in partials folder are render with html structure of index.html present in view folder + their own html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `angular-ui-router`, but if you're stuck with using `ngRoute` then you could do something like the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-route.js"></script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'landing.html'
      }).when('/admin', {
        templateUrl: 'admin.html',
        data: {
          headerFooterVisible: false
        }
      });
    });

    function MainCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, prev) {
        $scope.headerFooterVisible = !current.data || current.data.headerFooterVisible;
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-show="headerFooterVisible" ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <div ng-show="headerFooterVisible" ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This way allows you to specify in the router config which routes should hide the header and footer. Just add `headerFooterVisible: false` to the `data` section of the route config for the routes that you don't want the header and footer visible.

Comment: i will surely try this.