# How to access userinfo in angularjs application after successful login

Tags: angularjs

im developing an test application in angularjs and authenticating my user from login page, 
Express Code:

```
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {    
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.json(401, error);    
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {          
      if (err) return res.send(err);
          res.json(req);
    });
  })(req, res, next);   

};
```

Service : (Auth and Session)
    Auth Service code:
    login: function(user, callback) {
            var cb = callback || angular.noop;

```
        return Session.Sessionlogin().save({
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password

        }, function(user) {
          $rootScope.currentUser = user;
          return cb();
        }, function(err) {
          return cb(err);
        }).$promise;
      },
```

> Session Service Code:
>    Sessionlogin: function(){
>    return $resource('/api/session/');

```
 Controller Code:
     $scope.login = function(form) {      
          $scope.submitted = true;               
          if(form.$valid) {
            Auth.login({
              email: $scope.user.email,
              password: $scope.user.password                  
            })
            .then( function(err) {
              // todo : redirect to admin dashboard
              $location.path('admin/dashboard');
            })
            .catch( function(err) { 
              err = err.data;
              $scope.errors.other = err.message;

            });
          }
        };
```

every thing work fine now my question is :
after successful login im redirecting the user to dashboard page.Now how can i access the userinfo in dashboard page.Is there any kind of `session object in angularjs where i can store the response received from the express code and send it to the dashboard page.`

Comment: Not by default. But you could, of course, create one.

Comment: could you shed some light on this.

Comment: Personally, i would go for a user service. If a user logs in successfully, i would store the necessary information in this service and inject it everywhere i need access to the current users data. feel free to add some information if i got something wrong or anything is unclear. I've got a feeling like we're dealing with a 'wrap your head around the concept' issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share data around an angular app, you can either:

- Store the data in a service which can then be injected into controllers whenever you need to access that data. Services are singletons: there'll only ever be one instance of each service which is why the data is persistent across controllers.
- Store data in `$rootScope`. It looks like you've already set the user object on the root scope, so you can access it as `$rootScope.currentUser` provided that you have injected `$rootScope` into your controller. Note that it's not usually a good idea to litter the root scope, but in this case I think it is wise to store the user object there because you will probably need to access it from a lot of views.

I usually store the user object in `$rootScope` (so that it's accessible from views) *and* in a dedicated service (so that it's accessible from controllers/etc).

Comment: Wouldn't storing the data in a $rootscope limit your ability to unit test the code; as it adds a global dependency to your application?  Your first option--creating a service [or Factory]--makes use of Angular's Dependency Injection features and I believe is considered the proper approach.

Comment: I'm fairly new to angular and not too familiar with angular unit testing, so you're probably right. Is it ok to store the user object there if its only purpose is to assist with view rendering? I usually need the user object to be accessible from a lot of views, and I feel like injecting the service and assigning $scope.currentUser for each controller is overkill.

Comment: From what I've seen elsewhere, the service is usually added to the $scope variable inside the controller if it needs to be shared with a view; sort of like this `$scope.myService = serviceArgument`

Comment: Decade Moon life saver.. can u have a look @ my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643926/angularjs-full-stack-application